# Google Analytics does not work with blogdown

Tags: r, google-analytics, hugo, blogdown

I use the hugo-academic theme. As Google Analytics did not work I noticed that [Google Analytics Templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/internal/#google-analytics) were missing.

```
{{ template "_internal/google_analytics.html" . }}
{{ template "_internal/google_analytics_async.html" . }}
```

I added them to `single.html` and `list.html`.  I got no error message, but Google still did not track.

Then I added the complete code Google provides and tracking worked fine!

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-106XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

No idea what is wrong here. A problem with blogdown, Hugo or the academic-theme? Or just a confusion on my part?

Comment: It will be easier for us to diagnose your problem if you can provide a link to the page on which Google Analytics does not work, or your Github repo. If you are using Github + Netlify, you can get a unique URL for each commit, which means you will be able to show a historical page.

Comment: My repo is: https://github.com/petzi53/weblog
My website is: https://thought-splinters.netlify.com/
GA now works as I have added the Google script. Should I remove it?

The developer of hugo-academic theme says that [GA works for him](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/269#issuecomment-328626871) perfect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like a TOML issue. I don't completely understand it (might be a bug of Hugo or a certain TOML parser, or it is just how TOML works). but you need to move your top-level options in config.toml to the beginning of the config file. For example, your [current config.toml](https://github.com/petzi53/weblog/blob/48019a6668aed0f4483c38dc2d6c1a7faad14f75/config.toml) looks like this:

```
baseurl = "/"  # End your URL with a `/` trailing slash.

....

[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

# Enable comments by entering your Disqus shortname
disqusShortname = "petzi"

# Enable analytics by entering your Google Analytics tracking ID
GoogleAnalytics = "UA-106334854-2"

....
```

Change the order of options to:

```
baseurl = "/"  # End your URL with a `/` trailing slash.

# Enable comments by entering your Disqus shortname
disqusShortname = "petzi"

# Enable analytics by entering your Google Analytics tracking ID
GoogleAnalytics = "UA-106334854-2"

....

[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

....
```

Comment: Excellent! Changing the order works for some reason. strange though.